# Countif function in R by fixing the range column

Tags: r

How to do countif in R

IN EXCEL we can write the formula as

```
"COUNTIF($K$2:$K$205,K2),COUNTIF($K$2:$K$205,K3),.... "
```

How to do in R

```
value   col Countif
 1       A  3
 1       A  3
 1       A  3
 4       A  2
 4       A  2
 3       A  1
 99      B  2
 99      B  2
1000     B  4
1000     B  4
1000     B  4
1000     B  4
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use the convenient function from `dplyr` i.e. `add_count`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     add_count(value, col)
```

which is similar to

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(value, col) %>%
    mutate(count = n())
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun , this works